# big integers when reading file with readr in r

Tags: r, readr

I wanted to use the `readr` package since I will work on some bigger files in the future. My problem is, that there is a column called `Intensity` which has some very big values (e.g. `5493500000`). My problem is, the first time this big value appears is in line 2200 and `readr` already defined the column as `integer` instead of `numeric` and produces a buffer overflow.

Is there a way to only provide a single column type to the `read_tsv` function, since I don't want to provide all (about) 40 columns the correct type.

Any help os appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need the argument `col_types = cols(Intensity = col_double())`, as per the manual, this will prevent imputation of the column type based on the first 1000 rows. If you only want a subset of the columns use `cols_only`.

Comment: I didn't got the syntax correctly and was wondering if I now need to provide for each column the correct data type. Didn't got I can also overwrite a single type! Tanks thats solves my question.