# How to use wildcards to define col_type when using readr?

Tags: r, wildcard, readr

I just asked a few days ago, how to set a specific column type when using `readr` package. [big integers when reading file with readr in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894729/big-integers-when-reading-file-with-readr-in-r)

Is there a way to define the column names by wildcard? In my case, I have sometimes several columns starting with `Intensity` and an appendix depending on the experiment. It is hard to use `read_tsv` in a function if you not know upfront which project names where used.

So something like `col_types = cols('Intensity.*' = col_double())` would be awesome.

Anyone an idea how to get this feature?

**EDIT:**
Maybe something like read the first 2 lines, `grep` 'Intensity' in the `names` and then somehow create this parameter like `cols(Intensity=col_double(), 'Intensity pg'=col_double(), 'Intensity hs'=col_double())`.
But I have no idea how to create this parameter value on the fly.

Comment: Maybe you can build up sth upon `txt <- "foo,bar1,bar2\n1,2,3";matches <- grep("^bar\\d+", strsplit(readLines(textConnection(txt), n=1),",",T)[[1]], value=T);read_csv(txt, col_types=setNames(rep(list(col_character()), length(matches)), matches))`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I was not aware I can just provide a list to the `col_types`. Perfect. Would u write an answer so I can give credit?!

Comment: You can set a `.default` if you wrap the specifications in `cols`, which may be useful, depending on how many columns of what type you have.

Comment: It is pretty mixed from integer to text. So the `.default` wouldn't help much I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I add the answer which solved my question, based on the comment of lukeA...

```
read_MQtsv <- function(file) {
  require('readr')
  jnk <- read.delim(file, nrows=1, check.names=FALSE)
  matches <- grep('Intensity|LFQ|iBAQ', names(jnk), value=TRUE)
  read_tsv(file, 
           col_types=setNames(
             rep(list(col_double()), length(matches)), 
             matches))
}
```

So I adapted the single line from the comment to a new function which I would use when reading my special files which are produced by a program called `MaxQuant`.